# How to print a filepath in R Markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm trying to print a filepath in Rmd as part of a log. The path is passed to the R markdown file, so it comes in as a character string. \ is a special character for both R and LaTeX, which is used to render the final document. Currently, the file paths use \ so that they can be used in the parent R function to actually load the files. What do I need to replace this with in order to actually print it to the pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it by `/` or `\\\\` - the latter one "escapes" the backslash actually twice.